# Convert SQL blob/bytea in dump to string in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, character-encoding, bytea

I have a pg_dump of a table that contains a column of type bytea. It is a long string like: `\\x4e696365206d7573696361...`

Normally in SQL I would use a simple:

```
SELECT user_id,
       encode(text_column::bytea, 'escape')
FROM posts
LIMIT 10
```

And that provides the original text.

How can I convert this in Python? I've been trying `.encode`/`.decode`/`base64encode` etc but no luck.

Comment: can you provide an example of string and it bytea representation(i.e. for example `\\xdeadbeaf == hello world`)?

Comment: Example: `\x54657374` --> `Test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, following to your example its simple `hex` representation.

```
>>> '\\x48414e44203330'.lstrip('\\x').decode('hex')
'HAND 30'
```